# image and string in same label in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, viewwillappear

I have image and string in label togher in navigation bar

[image]

When I use coins, say use all 50 of them it should be 0 with image coins but its not

[image]

but when I click to another viewcontroller and back to same viewcontroller with coins the image is back

[image]

here is code:

```
let coinLabel = UILabel()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {


    // Set icon in label in navigation bar ////
    let image = UIImage(named: "coins.jpeg")
    let newSize = CGSize(width: 15, height: 15)

    //Resize image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
    image?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
    let imageResized = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Create attachment text with image
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = imageResized
    let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
    let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(coins)")

    myString.appendAttributedString(attachmentString)
    coinLabel.attributedText = myString

    coinLabel.sizeToFit()

    // Set defined label to navigation bar right corner
    let leftItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: coinLabel)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = leftItem
    coinLabel.font = coinLabel.font.fontWithSize(15)


}
```

I think the problem is with reloading... or something. Any Idea??

Comment: How are you updating the `attributedText` on the `UILabel`? My bet is you're not attaching the image again.

Comment: @originaluser2 yes its not updating, how do I solve update?

Comment: You included three images in your question. The attributed text of the textfield in image 1 and 3 is set up in your `viewWillAppear` method, triggered by the view appearing. The attributed text of the textfield in image 2 is set up elsewhere, triggered from using coins.

Comment: only thing that is helping to c/p all this code in button that is + or - coins ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure that it's a reason but at least you need to set font before calling sizeToFit()

```
coinLabel.font = coinLabel.font.fontWithSize(15)    
coinLabel.sizeToFit()
```

Also you missed call to super.viewWillAppear(animated)

Comment: didnt change anything